# Error when creating private subnets within AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, cidr

I am currently trying to create a VPC with multiple subnets in AWS.  Unfortunately, whenever I go to design the subnets within the VPC I am getting errors. This is my VPC design:

VPC: 10.82.0.0/16

Private Subnets:

- 10.82.96.0/21
- 10.82.119.0/21
- 10.82.194.0/21
- 10.82.212.0/21

The Error I get is the following for each subnet CIDR except 10.82.96.0/21:

> Must be a valid CIDR block.

What am I doing wrong? I just want to create multiple private subnets in this VPC.

Answer (score 3):

A `/21` is quite an unusual netmask to be using. It contains 2048 IP addresses.

The netmask for `/21` would be:

```
11111111.11111111.11111000.00000000
```

Only the zeroes are allowed to change. In binary, `100000000000` is equivalent to 2048 in decimal and `1000` in binary is **8 in decimal**.

This means that the second last number would be a **multiple of 8** (eg 0, 8, 16, 32).

However, **you have not chosen IP addresses that start in a /21 range**.

Your chosen subnets would have the following IP address ranges:

```
CIDR            First address   Last address
10.82.96.0/21   10.82.96.0      10.82.103.255  Good!
10.82.119.0/21  10.82.112.0     10.82.119.255  Invalid
10.82.194.0/21  10.82.192.0     10.82.199.255  Invalid
10.82.212.0/21  10.82.208.0     10.82.215.255  Invalid
```

Note that the first line is good because 96 is **divisible by 8**. Therefore, it is valid in a `/21` CIDR.

However, the subsequent lines do not start on a `/21` boundary. They are **invalid CIDR values**.

I highly recommend using a [CIDR calculator](https://www.google.com/search?q=cidr+calculator) when determining difficult IP ranges.

Comment: Why does it have to be a multiple of 8 in this case?

Comment: I've added netmask details to explain why the second-last digit would need to be a multiple of 8.